# React native header issue

Tags: react-native, header, react-native-ios

I want to add a header with a title and a subtitle in the center .
Can anyone please explain how to do this ? I am unable to view the header.

Comment: Are you using react navigation?

Comment: Yes ... Is there a way to do it without react navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Header component of native-base and it works both in android and ios and there are lots of other components there

https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref